# how to get the value inside the function in js and pass to my input text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, slim-lang

here's the scenario
i'm done how to get the last id of the employees but i cant pass the value in my input text i'm using angularjs on this

my html.slim

```
md-input-container flex="50"
    label Employee Number
    input ng-model="employees"
```

in my controller.coffee

```
$scope.employees = Employee.query (data)->
 $scope.text = data.length + 1
```

dont mind the "ctrl" thing i setup my angular to that.

is there anyone know how to pass the value text to my view?

Comment: does `{{ text }}` not work in your slim file?  You could use `ng-bind="text"`

Comment: nope im using angular material input